# Добавить значение переменной при нажатии на картинку

Tags: python

Хочу, что-бы при нажатии на кнопку к переменной balance добавлялось 1. Вот мой код :

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
import time
from config import balance
root=Tk()
root.title("ClickGame")


start = Label(root, text="Баланс :",font=("Arial", 12))
start.pack()
def startt():
    print(balance)
    balance + 1


play_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="play.png")
active_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="stop.png")
pbutton=Button(root, image=play_icon,command=lambda: startt())).pack()
root.bind()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот это:

```
balance + 1
```

надо заменить на это:

```
balance += 1
```

Также вот это:

```
pbutton=Button(root, image=play_icon,command=lambda: startt())).pack()
```

можно заменить на это:

```
pbutton=Button(root, image=play_icon,command=startt)).pack()
```

lambda используется тогда, когда вам надо передать какие-то аргументы функции

Comment: Unresolved reference 'balance' ошибка, я попробовал сделать balance =+ 1, ругается на print с той же ошибкой, если их заменяю местами, ошибки нету. но если я запускаю программу, жму на кнопку, и нету принта в консоли, как я понимаю не вызывается функция по нажатию на кнопку

Comment: Вы исправили этот фрагмент кода?
pbutton=Button(root, image=play_icon,command=startt)).pack()

Comment: И что тогда вообще balance? Какого она типа(int, float, dict...)? Возможно это функция. И да, balance не увеличиться, если вы не сделаете balance += 1.И попрообуйте сначала сделать balance += 1, а потом print(balance)

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
import time
from config import balance
root=Tk()
root.title("ClickGame")


start = Label(root, text="Баланс :",font=("Arial", 12))
start.pack()
def startt():
    balance += 1
    print(balance)

play_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="play.png")
active_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="stop.png")
pbutton=Button(root, image=play_icon,command=startt).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/12oygpi

Comment: А, добавьте в начало функции: global balance

Comment: https://prnt.sc/12oypho

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку эта ошибка

Comment: А вы добавили global balance?

Comment: да, как вы говорили. https://prnt.sc/12oyzbz

Comment: Скопируйте код ниже. Вы не там написали global balance

Comment: Вроде-бы уже так, но ошибка... https://prnt.sc/12oz6bh

Comment: Вы забыли импортировать balance.from config import balance

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное) дальше у меня только визуализация!) Удачи вам в жизни

Comment: Я рад, что мы разобрались в этом вопросе. Удачи и вам в изучении python!

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
import time
from config import balance
root=Tk()
root.title("ClickGame")


start = Label(root, text="Баланс :",font=("Arial", 12))
start.pack()
def startt():
    global balance
    balance += 1
    print(balance)

play_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="play.png")
active_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="stop.png")
pbutton=Button(root, image=play_icon,command=startt).pack()
root.mainloop()
```